# Browser caching is not working for all .js files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, browser-cache

I use the following code for browser caching in my .htaccess:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


##js-Dateien ins browser-caching einbeziehen
<filesMatch "\\.(js|js.gz)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesMatch>
##Ende js-Dateien ins browser-caching einbeziehen

# Deflate Compression by FileType
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>

# turns cache on for 1 month
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

But when i run run Pagespeed insight there are several .js files which are not included in the browser caching for example:

```
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 (2 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.3.1 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…-wordpress/js/mappress.min.js?ver=2.43.4 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…-shortcodes/includes/js/rsvp.js?ver=1.82 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…s/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…s/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2 (2,5 Tage)
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…s/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.4 (2,5 Tage)
```

why these files are not included?

Comment: Because of `ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"`?

Comment: mh.. i will check this tomorrow. but i dont think this is the mistake...

Comment: no thats not the problem. when i delete the line 'ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"' there is no difference...has anybody an other idea what is wrong in my hatccess???

Comment: Update all `access x year/days` to `access plus x days/years`. Do not forget the `plus`.

Comment: for example i make `ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"`??

Comment: nothing...same like before...

Comment: Looking at the response header, the `Expires` header appears to work correctly: `Date: Mon, 04 Jan 2016 18:07:15 GMT` and `Expires: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 18:07:15 GMT`

Answer (score 0):

It is because it doesn't recognize the extension.

instead of reading this

```
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…jquery.form.min.js
```

it reads this :

```
http://www.hwi-sicherheit.de/…s/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1
```

Remove the query string and encode the parameters

I think you should check this : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/